# How to draw four boundary corner for qr code scanner

Tags: android

[image]

How to draw four Boundary for qrcode?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I created a vector drawable for this:

```
<vector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="220dp" android:height="220dp" android:viewportHeight="230.0" android:viewportWidth="230.0">
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M165,5C178.2,5 198.2,5 225,5L225,30.79L225,65"
        android:strokeColor="@color/qr_code_reader_square" android:strokeWidth="10"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M5,65C5,51.8 5,31.8 5,5L30.79,5L65,5"
        android:strokeColor="@color/qr_code_reader_square" android:strokeWidth="10"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M165,225C178.2,225 198.2,225 225,225L225,199.21L225,165"
        android:strokeColor="@color/qr_code_reader_square" android:strokeWidth="10"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M5,165C5,178.2 5,198.2 5,225L30.79,225L65,225"
        android:strokeColor="@color/qr_code_reader_square" android:strokeWidth="10"/>
</vector>
```

You can save it in `res/drawable` as `qr_code_reader_square.xml` and then use it in your layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@drawable/qr_code_reader_square"/>
```

You will also have to set the color in `res/values/colors.xml`:

```
<color name="qr_code_reader_square">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```

Comment: Can you tell how to make the border little small...when i try to change the it's not looking good..please guid me sir

Comment: Hi @GowthamanM, you have to change the value in `android:strokeWidth` to do that. Make sure to change it in all the `path` tags with the same value. I hope that helps.

Comment: how to make the corner of each path as curved??

Comment: @SachinVarma you'll have to create another vector drawable for that. Changing the current one for that change is too complex and I have no idea how to do it. But if you create another image in Sketch and export it as SVG then you can export it as a vector drawable and use it like I used the one above.

Comment: Ok mahn, thanks for the reply, i did it through some hack way. Anyway good answer, it may help me in future. Very much happy to give you a +1.

Comment: how to dim the background ?

Comment: Hey @ralphgabb, I actually haven't done the background dim yet. I need to do it for my app but I've been delaying that cause of higher priority tickets. I think you'll need to do that by adding 4 views (1 for the left of the reader, 1 for the right, 1 for the top and 1 for the bottom) with the semi-transparent background. I don't think you can do it with only one. Hope that helps!

Comment: I have made the background dim using a layerlist, and utilising your vector drawable. It works.

Comment: @DivyaGupta Any thoughts on how to add border-radius to those edges? Thanks.

Comment: @jayanthsaikiran sorry for the late reply. But I tried many methods, and can't find a working solution for adding border-radius to those edges. If you find some method, please post as a separate answer or comment.

Answer (score 4):

Use the below drawable file and set the background of QR Code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="@color/black" android:width="5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>
    <item android:left="20dp" android:right="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="20dp" android:bottom="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: The inner part is not transparent. How can it be like in the picture

Comment: You can utilise the @Franco's code combined with layerlist, and it will look 90% similar to above image, only difference might be the square boundaries will be inside the semi-transparent background.

Answer (score 1):

I shortened the edges. It looks better now.

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp" android:height="200dp" android:viewportHeight="230.0" android:viewportWidth="230.0">
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M200,5C197.1,5 198,5 225,5L225,30.79L225,6"
        android:strokeColor="@color/colorWhite" android:strokeWidth="2"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M5,15C5,51.8 5,5 5,5L10.19,5L30,5"
        android:strokeColor="@color/colorWhite" android:strokeWidth="2"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M200,225C200,225 200,225 225,225L225,200.21L225,200"
        android:strokeColor="@color/colorWhite" android:strokeWidth="2"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M5,200C5,200 5,210 5,225L30.90,225L7,225"
        android:strokeColor="@color/colorWhite" android:strokeWidth="2"/>

</vector>
```

You should check down :

[image]

Comment: @Abhi25t I just added a border.

Comment: how to make it to blur around

Comment: @HuyNguyen Blur appeared while taking a screenshot.

Comment: @halilozel1903 I already have known the solution. To use custom view with canvas

Comment: Any thoughts on how to add border-radius to those edges?

Comment: @jayanthsaikiran I haven't tried it, but I can give a rough idea on how it can be done. Use a layerlist and use a shape with some corner and radius tags in that shape. Try and see if it works.

Comment: Any way to do this in compose?

Comment: @HalilOzel, In my case, i see a gap between the corners and the outer square. How can i avoid the gap ? My square size is 300dp X 300dp. The corners are not exactly placed on the square, instead they are inside the square. How can i place the corners exactly on the square ?